# Python regular expressions, how to add valid characters to negation sub-section

Tags: python, regex

In the following Python regular expression:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"""
^                     # Match start of line.
([^\W\d]+)            # One or more word characters (including ê, etc.; but excluding 0-9) 
                      # as a returned group. Not \W and not \d.
$                     # Match end of line.
""", re.VERBOSE + re.UNICODE)
```

how can I add the - character (dash) as a valid character in the []?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pipe` to merge two regex:

```
((?:[^\W\d]|-)+)
```

Comment: but `\w` includes digits also

Comment: Does the ?: prevent the added () from being returned as a group?

Comment: @Superdooperhero. Yes. That is used for creating a non-capturing group.